# rsync - restore from multiple (identical) sources to one target

Tags: rsync, restore, source

Im wonder if there is way to `rsync` (or any other tool) from multiple identical sources to one target.

My thought was, one rsync process reads the filelist from the beginning, the other one from the end. When both meets on the same file, the process is complete.

Background is, i have a NAS and a external HDD, where are 1:1 the same files stored.
To increase the restore speed, i want to read from both sources. The destination is in this example not the bottleneck, differen then the sources.

I know that rsnyc supports multiple source paths

```sh
rsync -r root@source1.lan:/... root@source2.lan:/... ./dest
```

But what happens if both sources are identical?

What would be the best solution?

Any thoughts are welcome!

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I found this: https://superuser.com/a/370855/952138 But it feels like there must be a better approach